# React JSDOM - How to access width of an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, jsdom

Using React TestUtils and jsdom, how to access the **width** of a node by the `getDOMNode` or `findDOMNode` call? I cant find any api's listed, so for now have to work out like this : 
`someElement.getDOMNode().style._values.width`, which is a hacky solution. I would like some cleaner solution to access the dom api's

Comment: code example would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

The `getDOMNode` call returns the actual DOM node so you can do all of the usual DOM operations.

However, JSDOM is only a DOM emulation library. A full layout window has not been implemented for it. It's a known issue that the normal `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight` properties do not work.

The issue is discussed here: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/135

Comment: Updated this answer with what I found after looking into it further.